# Taylor Series of a composition of functions

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have to find a Maclaurin series of the following function:

$y = D\sin(C\arctan(Bx - E(Bx - \arctan(Bx)))) + Sh$

I wasn't able to find it by hand.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm assuming $S$ is a constant... This looks like a pain to calculate by hand. Wolfram Alpha gives me this:

$$S+BCDx-\frac{x^3}{3!}(B^3CD)\left(C^2 + 2(E+1)\right) - \frac{x^5}{5!}(B^5CD)\left(C^4 + 20C^2(E+1) + 8(8E+3)\right) + \mathcal{O}(x^7)$$

which looks daunting, yet interesting.

Comment: Yep, I forgot about Wolfram Alpha, haven't used in for awhile. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using Wolfram Alpha.

```
Series[A + D Sin[C ArcTan[B x - E (B x - ArcTan[B x])]], {x, 0, 12}]
```